# Is there a python function for spatio-temporal clustering?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, spatial, clickhouse, temporal

I'm working with a dataset with latitude, longitude and date-time, and 5 million points per day.
And I don't have an expected number of cluster, and depending on the day it should change.

I'm coding in `Python`, with a `clickhouse database` to store the source data.

==> Is there a way to do a `spatiotemporal clustering` that includes the 3 features?

So far I have scaled/normalized the 3 features and use MiniBatchKMeans (the current solution used), or a `Euclidian distance`, but  I'm losing the notion of the physical distance between points.

`DBSCAN` or `HDBSCAN` with `Havresine` is accepting only 2 features (lat lon in radians).

Also, the volume rule-out non-optimized solution that doesn't scale (I’ve tried the ST-DBSCAN available on GitHub, I stopped it after the 15h run on just 2 hours of data).

I expect to get clusters of my datapoints regrouping nearest points in location and time together.

Comment: just remark: Since you use ClickHouse make sense to look at [Catboost](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/guides/apply_catboost_model/) engine? Maybe it could provide some clustering features.

Comment: I just had a quick look, i just see classifier and regressor but no clustering so in my case i don't see the value. Is there clustering models ?

Comment: unfortunately, I am not spec in CatBoost - you could ask this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catboost